# How to undo the deletion of characters in insert mode caused by Ctrl-U?

Tags: undo-redo

I changed my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and as I'm still getting used to it I sometimes enter combinations I didn't intend to.

While in insert mode typing, having already written most of a long sentence, I accidentally pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>, which deleted all the characters I had typed so far.

Is there any way to undo this and get those characters back, without retyping them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't recover the words you've already lost, but we can make `<c-u>` an undo-able motion by remapping it:

```
inoremap <c-u> <c-g>u<c-u>
```

This is from [vim-sensible](https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible/blob/c82c6d4978be28adcf85dc1e61fa428e801bd525/plugin/sensible.vim#L96). See `:h i_CTRL-G_u`; essentially, the `<c-g>u` causes vim to 'break' the change at that point, meaning you can undo back to that point.